# Basic Question for limits and Taylor Expansion

Tags: limits, taylor-expansion, factorial

I am trying to solve a question for limits.
Is $1^x +2^x + 3^x + .....+ n^x$, a Taylor expansion for something?
What is the Taylor expansion for $n! $?

The question that I'm trying to solve is:-

$$\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \biggl(\frac{1^x +2^x + 3^x + .....+ n^x}{n}\biggr)^{1/x} $$

Comment: Perhaps try googling the question since it is apparent your expression is somewhat common and probably asked before https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-solve-lim-x-0-1-x-2-x-3-x-n-x-n-a-x

Comment: @MatthewLiu Thanks a lot.